# Create cyclic textview

Tags: android, textview, cyclic

I spill a lot of data into `TextView` and after sometime the first messages are less interesting.
Therefore I want to limit max lines to 40 and do the `TextView` Cyclic, then the 41 line will write at the first line in the 'TextView'

I know I can limit max lines using this attribute:

```
android:maxLines="40"
```

But I didn't found any effective way to do the `TextView` cyclic. Of course I can save the data in `Queue` and update the `TextView` each time but I don't think it's good and effective way…

Does there effective way to implement cyclic 'TextView'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Stringbuilder` class to append the `String` from index 0.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really great idea. Just do you think the cost of updating the all text (`TextView.settext(Stringbuilder.toString()`) is not so much? (I update the TextView 200 times in second)

Comment: @AsfK I have never tried it, so you should just try it out. However, I think it'll be fine if you don't make recurring instances of your objects.